# OutputStreams / Writers as observers

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, observer-pattern, observers

`InputStream`s / `Reader`s can be considered as `Iterator<Byte>`s / `Iterator<Char>`s, as they both represent non-strict, lazy data streams.

As the `Observer` is the categorical dual of `Iterator` (http://csl.stanford.edu/~christos/pldi2010.fit/meijer.duality.pdf), it is evident that `OutputStream` / `Writer` shares similar interface with `Observer<Byte>` / `Observer<Char>`.

How can a writer be thought as an `Observer` in the reactive sense? What is the asynchronous event stream here?

Comment: This is an open issue for reactive-IO. I thought a little bit about it but dualizing InputStream/OutputStream didn't yield anything promising for me. Certainly, <Byte> or <Char> it too fine grained but <byte[]> or <ByteBuffer> is a better candidate.

Comment: I consider it an Iterable<Byte> with an additional, arguably more efficient implementation of `readToArray(Byte[] arr)` than calling `next()` in a loop.